# if argument inside mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, function, variables

I have now three different PHP pages that contain almost the same information so to be able to reduce this to one page I need to have a php variable inside the mysql query.
Today it is like this:

```
$query1  = "SELECT * FROM `Yrker` WHERE `Kategori` = '1' AND `Bruk` = '1' ORDER BY yearstart DESC, mndstart DESC";`
```

I need that the " AND `Bruk` = '1'" is removed from this query-line if i put ?nobruk=no in the adressbar. Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: yes its possible, what have you tried ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to (and can't) put an `if` inside your query; you want to *use* an `if` to create your query based on some condition. There are lots of ways to write this, one of which is

```
if (!empty($_GET['nobruk'])) {
    $query1 = "SELECT ... WHERE `Kategori` = '1' ORDER BY ...";
}
else {
    $query1 = "SELECT ... WHERE `Kategori` = '1' AND `Bruk` = '1' ORDER BY ...";
}
```

Another way, which is shorter and involves the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), is

```
$includeBruk = empty($_GET['nobruk']);
$query1 = "SELECT ... WHERE `Kategori` = '1' ".
          ($includeBruk ? "AND `Bruk` = '1' " : "").
          "ORDER BY ...";
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple if statement:

```
$query1  = "SELECT * FROM `Yrker` WHERE `Kategori` = '1'";
  if ($_GET['nobruk']!='no') {
    $query1.=" AND `Bruk` = '1'";
  }
$query1.= " ORDER BY yearstart DESC, mndstart DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
<?php

$query = ($_REQUEST['nobruk'] == "no") ? "SELECT * FROM `Yrker` WHERE `Kategori` = '1' ORDER BY yearstart DESC, mndstart DESC": "SELECT * FROM `Yrker` WHERE `Kategori` = '1' AND `Bruk` = '1' ORDER BY yearstart DESC, mndstart DESC";
echo $query;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `Yrker` WHERE `Kategori`='1' ".($_GET['nobruk'] === 'no' ? "" : "AND `Bruk`='1' ")."ORDER BY yearstart DESC, mndstart DESC";
```

Comment: Thank you, I choose to use your suggestions since it made in my opionion the prettiest code.

Comment: No problem. I personally agree with using the shortest option possible.